# Using QtAV in qml

Tags: qt, video, qml

I am trying to use [QtAV](http://www.qtav.org/) library in QML following the instructions at this link https://github.com/wang-bin/QtAV/wiki/Deploy-SDK-Without-Building-QtAV. I have managed to successfully build the project, but I am unable to use the module in QML. In my .pro file I have `QT += av avwidgets`, then in my qml file I have `import QtAV 1.6`. I get the following error: `QtAV module not installed`.

Answer (score 0):

In your **qml** file instead of

```
import QtAV 1.6
```

point to your QtAV qml directory by this line

```
import "[QtAVSourceCodePath]/qml"
```

Then **make** your project again and try to rerun your program